# rgraph SVG getting 0 width and height

Tags: jquery, svg, rgraph

```js
$("#sparepartconsumption svg").attr("width", '800px');
$("#sparepartconsumption svg").attr("height", '500px');
console.log(datax)
console.log(datay)
var bar = new RGraph.SVG.HBar({
  id: 'sparepartconsumption',
  data: datax,
  options: {
    yaxisLabels: datay,
    xaxis: false,
    yaxis: false,
    colorsSequential: true,
    backgroundGridVlines: false,
    title: 'Consumption',
    titleColor: 'black',
    titleSize: 14,
    titleX: 240,
    titleY: 15,
    shadow: false,
    strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    textFont: 'Roboto-Black',
    textSize: 7,
    colors: ['#FFDE00', '#097054'],
    labelsAbove: true,
    // keyColors:  [ '#FFDE00', '#097054'],
    // key: legend,
    // keyPosition: 'graph',
    textAccessible: true,
  }
}).grow({
  frames: 60
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 90%; height: 500px; float:left" id="sparepartconsumption">

</div>
```

Sample Data:

```
["NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004"]

["5.000","5.000","5.000","5.000","5.000","10.000","10.000","40.000","50.000"]
```

[image]

[image]

I am generating a graph using rgraph. Data are all good problem is SVG is gettin 0 width and height. Tried setting the width and height using jQuery but it didnt help.

1. Why is my SVG getting 0 width and height?
2. How to fix this problem?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: datax is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

1. You have defined no svg element in your code. Your browser returns `0` because you ask for the `width` and `height` of an element that does not exist.
2. Just add `<svg></svg>` inside your `div`.

*EDIT after comment*

I answered your questions. If you wanted to ask how to place an svg element with `Rgraph` and edit its size, you should ask that.

First, answer N. 1 almost stands. You try to set the `width` and `height` of an `svg` element that does not yet exist. It will be created later on with the `new RGraph.SVG.HBar` statement. Therefore, the first two lines of your javascript do nothing.

Second, the most likely reason for the result is that the `svg` element is not created properly. There are several issues with the code. I made a working example to illustrate them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../libraries/RGraph.svg.common.core.js" ></script>

    <script src="../libraries/RGraph.svg.hbar.js" ></script>


    <title>RGraph demo</title>


    <meta name="description" content="An SVG HBar Chart " />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />

<script>

var datay = ["NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004","NS0000004"];

var datax = [5.000,5.000,5.000,5.000,5.000,10.000,10.000,40.000,50.000];

$(document).ready(function(){
var bar = new RGraph.SVG.HBar({
  id: 'sparepartconsumption',
  data: datax,
  options: {
    yaxisLabels: datay,
    xaxis: false,
    yaxis: false,
    colorsSequential: true,
    backgroundGridVlines: false,
    title: 'Consumption',
    titleColor: 'black',
    titleSize: 14,
    titleX: 240,
    titleY: 15,
    shadow: false,
    strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    textFont: 'Roboto-Black',
    textSize: 7,
    colors: ['#FFDE00', '#097054'],
    labelsAbove: true,
    // keyColors:  [ '#FFDE00', '#097054'],
    // key: legend,
    // keyPosition: 'graph',
    textAccessible: true,
  }
}).grow({
  frames: 60
});
$("#sparepartconsumption svg").attr("width", '800px');
$("#sparepartconsumption svg").attr("height", '500px');
console.log(datax)
console.log(datay)
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 90%; height: 500px; float:left" id="sparepartconsumption">

</div>

</body>
```

Things to notice:

- Your `datax` array contained strings, it should contain numbers (no double quotes).
- If you use `jquery`, you need to make sure that the containing `div` element exists when you use it. That is why the `Rgraph` element is wrapped inside a `$(document).ready(function(){}) block.
- As you can see, the code changing the size of the `svg` element is at the end. It is not necessary, as `Rgraph` will set a size depending on the parent element.
- If you try this code, make sure the `src` of the script elements points to the correct path. In my system, it was `../libraries/RGraph.svg.common.core.js` and `../libraries/RGraph.svg.hbar.js`, but YMMV.

Comment: RGraph creates the SVG tag for you  - inside the DIV tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago - it was due to me not using the correct **namespace** on the SVG tag.

The code that creates an SVG tag in RGraph is this:

```
    var svg = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute('style', 'top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute');
        svg.setAttribute('width', container.offsetWidth);
        svg.setAttribute('height', container.offsetHeight);
        svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1');
        svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
        svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
        svg.__object__    = obj;
        svg.__container__ = container;
    container.appendChild(svg);
```

(it won't work if you just use that - it needs modifying for your environment).

If you just pass the ID of the DIV tag then RGraph will create an SVG inside it for you - or if you really want to create it yourself then look at the RGraph.SVG.createSVG() function - you should be able to copy it into your own codebase if you really want to (you'll need to modify it of course).

Comment: `If you just pass the ID of the DIV tag then RGraph will create an SVG inside it for you` this is the step i used i expect the graph to be created but i dont understand why it has no width and height

Comment: Do the demo pages work? if so copy the source code from one of those.